# Is `<wbr></wbr>` the same as `<wbr>`?

Tags: html, tags

When viewing the source of a website I realized that it is different in Firefox and Chrome.

A single tag `<wbr>` in Chrome is displayed as `<wbr></wbr>` in Firefox.

Are they the same?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well that's quite odd. When I use word break I never use a closing tag as it's used to insert in to a sentence. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_wbr.asp

Comment: @WilliamHarvey: sorry I didn't view the source by "righ-click, View page source" (I have checked and in this mode, the source code are identical) but instead I viewed them in developer mode (i.e. F12). A bug maybe.

Comment: When using the Object Inspector (Developer mode) you are viewing the interpreted source ie. the DOM. The right click "view source" is the actual response from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely because you're looking either in Firefox's "Developer Mode" or Firebug. This tends to show closing tags even when they aren't defined or required. Viewing the pure HTML source (i.e. `view-source:https://www.site.tld/example-url`) should only show the base HTML tag.

`<wbr>` doesn't require a closing tag in HTML 4 or 5, so it should be fine to use as is.

<sub>Note that if you're using XHTML then you will need to self-close as `<wbr />`</sub>